# Iterative HeapSort, but only change the one function ( heapify)

Tags: python

Can someone can help me to change the code of function `def heapify(arr, heapSize, k)` so it would be `Iterative` not Recursive? I can't figure it out, because it is preferred to change only the code of one function, leaving the others without change.
Code:

```
def heapify(arr, heapSize, k):
    smallest = k  # root
    l = 2 * k + 1  # left son
    r = 2 * k + 2  # right  son
    while True:
        if l < heapSize and arr[l] < arr[k]:
            smallest = l
        else:
            smallest = k
        if r < heapSize and arr[r] < arr[smallest]:
            smallest = r
        if smallest != k:
            arr[k], arr[smallest] = arr[smallest], arr[k]
            heapify(arr, heapSize, smallest)
        return arr


def buildHeap(arr):
    o = int((len(arr) - 2) / 2)

    for k in range(o, -1, -1):
        heapify(arr, heapSize, k)
    return arr


def heapSort(arr):
    arr = buildHeap(arr)
    heapSize = len(arr)
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1, 0, -1):
        arr[0], arr[heapSize - 1] = arr[heapSize - 1], arr[0]
        heapSize -= 1
        heapify(arr, heapSize, 0)
    return arr

arr = [10, 20, 15, 17, 9, 21]
heapSize = len(arr)
heapSort(arr)
print(arr)
```

Comment: Hope this helps https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-heap-sort/

Comment: Yeah i tried following this guide, but the heapsort and buildheap functions are diffrent there , i have to apply iterative only to the heapify func

Answer (score 3):

Making `heapify` iterative doesn't require that many changes because the only recursive call is pretty much a [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call); the recursive call is the final action of the function (the `return arr` could be considered 'after' the recursive call to `heapify`, but the return value isn't used anywhere in your code).

With tail calls, you don't need to worry about creating an explicit stack, and can just use a `while` loop with a flag (or alternatively, use `break`), and replace the actual call with just a write to the relevant variable(s). Every loop corresponds to another recursive call in your original function, so make sure to re-initialise all your variable *inside* the loop.

With that in mind, here is how you might modify your `heapify` to be iterative:

```py
def heapify(arr, heapSize, k):
    done = False

    while not done:
        smallest = k  # root
        l = 2 * k + 1  # left
        r = 2 * k + 2  # right

        if l < heapSize and arr[l] < arr[k]:
            smallest = l
        else:
            smallest = k
        if r < heapSize and arr[r] < arr[smallest]:
            smallest = r

        if smallest != k:
            arr[k], arr[smallest] = arr[smallest], arr[k]
            k = smallest
        else:
            done = True
```